# Using xml transformations in unit tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, slowcheetah, xslt

### Background:

Currently we have around 10 unit/integration test projects that hit a database to do tests.  Each test class that hits the database inherits from a class called `IntegrationTest` which is in a seperate dll called `TestBase`. `TestBase` contains a configuration file (nhibernate_log4net.cfg.xml) that houses the connection string to the database.

Our development team is a group of about 7 or 8.  If two team members were to run the unit tests at the same time there would be conflicts because a lot of the tests are adding and deleting data that is common across many tests.  This would cause tests to fail erroneously between the two developers.

### Layout:

**TestBase.dll**
IntegrationTest.cs  (Contains **[DeploymentItem("nhibernate_log4net.cfg.xml"]**)
nhibernate_log4net.cfg.xml
nhibernate_log4net.cfg.Developer 1.xml  (Transformation file)
nhibernate_log4net.cfg.Developer 2.xml  (Transformation file)
...

**UnitTest.dll**
References -> **TestBase.dll**
MyUnitTest.cs (Inherits from IntegrationTest in **TestBase.dll**)

### Problem:

My idea was to use `SlowCheetah` xml transformations on the configuration file in the `TestBase` dll for each developer in the team but the transformed file does not get copied to the **Out** directory of the unit test. The base configuration file (non transformed one) is the one that gets copied out to the **Out** directory.  I have a feeling it's because of the `[DeploymentItem("nhibernate_log4net.cfg.xml")` attribute I have to use to get the config file out there in the first place.

**Is there any way to use xml transformations on an xml config file that is included in a separate dll than the unit testing project?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually run the transforms by calling a target from msbuild, as outlined here: http://sedodream.com/2010/04/26/ConfigTransformationsOutsideOfWebAppBuilds.aspx

**UPDATE**

I have been able to reproduce your problem. It's subtle but I think it's working as expected. Here's what's happening:

- The config transform is being applied. The transformed file is placed in the *TestBase* output directory.
- You've specified *[DeploymentItem("nhibernate_log4net.cfg.xml")]* in your tests but this fails because the file is not relative to the *UnitTest* project. To compensate, you marked your config file with the *"Copy Local"=true*
- The "Copy Local" ensures that the content from TestBase project is copied to the UnitTest project, but it's either copying the pre-transformed file from the source location or it's moving the file in the bin folder before the XmlTransform task runs. (I'm inclined to think it's the former)

Few suggestions to address this:

1. Move the config file to the *UnitTest* library and apply the transforms there, this will ensure that the config is readily available to the test runner as intended; or
2. Configure the deployment options in the TestSettings file (instead of the DeploymentItemAttribute) to copy the generated file from the *TestBase* folder. (<Solution Directory>\TestBase\bin\Debug\cfg.xml); or
3. Change your projects so that they all share the same Output directory. This will ensure that the DeploymentItem attribute will copy the transformed TestBase configuration file to the TestRun folder. (Incidentally, a shared output folder is a great way to speed up your build because dependencies and content do not need to be copied again and again)

(Also, mad props out to @SayedIbrahimHashimi who is one of the main contributors behind SlowCheetahXml -- big fan, dig this extension a lot)

Comment: That's right for this case using the TransformXml task is the recommended approach.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi Using the TransformXml task doesn't appear to work for me.  It still does not copy the correct config file out to the **Out** directory of the unit test.  Currently the config file I was transforming was set to "Copy Always".  If I set that to "Do not copy" the config file is still transformed and put in build folder but it does not get copied to the **Out** folder at all.  It's almost like the unit test is trying to grab the file before it's transformed.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi I just tried moving the TransformXml task in the **BeforeBuild** and **AfterBuild** targets independently and neither seem to have any effect.  After I have set the "Copy to output directory" property to **Do not copy**

Comment: I don't follow how the dependent assemblies app.config file gets copied to the bin folder of the unit test project in the first place. This is not the standard behavior.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi I've elaborated a bit more on my scenario in my question above.  It turns out that I'm not able to even get the transformed xml file into the bin folder of the **UnitTest.dll** project in the first place.  If I set the **Copy to output directory** property to **Copy Always** it just copies the original config file (nhibernate_log4net.cfg.xml) and all of the transformation files to the **UnitTest.dll** bin folder. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @bryanbcook Thanks for all the effort you put in here Bryan.  I ended up using #2 and it looks like it's working!  #1 really wasn't going to work for me because I was trying to keep just one configuration file for all the unit test projects.  I could have over 50 unit test projects so I didn't want to have to use #1.

Answer (score -1):

[SlowCheetah - XML Transforms Free](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)

This package enables you to transform your app.config or any other XML file based on the build configuration. It also adds additional tooling to help you create XML transforms.

Comment: I already tried that as noted in my question.  The creator of **SlowCheetah** replied back in the comment and also acknowledged the answer that was already given.  I don't think you read the question and answer thoroughly.